# Creating email accounts without the registrar-Theory

Tags: http, email

I own a small domain on GoDaddy and I currently use their email service and pay a monthly fee for it. But I was thinking on how would it work to one be the owner of the email account itself, and create email address without involving the registrar. I dont know if I'm explaining myself but my question is more or less how do the protocol works to be able to create/manage email accounts. i.e Obviously gmail, and every single other webmail provider creates the accounts programatically without involving any registrar. Hows does it works?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you'll need to do is set up a '[MX record](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MX_record)' for your domain. This tells other email servers where to send email for some given domain; then you also need an email server to actually receive this email. On a Linux system, this would be something like postfix or exim, or even sendmail (not really recommended these days though). Or you could use a third-party free hosting service, and point MX records to them - eg, [google apps](http://www.google.com/apps/intl/en/group/index.html).

Comment: So lets say that I feel like opening a new webmail company. Would I still do this under my GoDaddy domain or I would need to transfer my domain?

Comment: You could do it under a godaddy domain - either add MX records manually if they let you, or point the nameservers to some other set of nameservers, and add MX records there.